# how to remove empty values in dc.js row chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I'm making a rowchart using the Dimensional Charting javascript library dc.js, which is based on d3 and crossfilter. I have created a row chart from the sale column.

I am having some issues in removing empty bins from a rowChart.

My csv file:

```
 partner    sale
  AMZ       newyear
  HD        newyear
  WAF       fallmake
  FEG       fallmake
  OVR       
  AMZ       fallmake
  FAU       balck
  HD         
  ATG       balck
```

My code:

```
 saleDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.sale; }),
 salegroup = saleDim.group().reduceCount(),
 nonEmptyHist11 = remove_bins(salegroup);
```

I have tried to remove empty sales bins using the following function:

```
function remove_bins(source_group) { // (source_group, bins...}
    return {
        all: function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function (d) {
                return d.sale!= null;
            });
        }
    };
}
```

My graph looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I could be missing something but shouldn't it be `d.sale !=null`?

Comment: @mkaran i m using d.sale !=null but this also not working

Comment: Take a look at this: https://plnkr.co/edit/wTwKH6vbPDCxiluqiniV?p=preview  If I have understood the problem correctly, you should check for an empty key `return d.key != "";` because salegroup is a dictionary that has sale values as keys and their count as values, thus " " has a value of 2. Take a look at the console of the plnkr. Hope it helps!

Comment: @mkaran Thank you it's working......using return d.key != "";